# How to add margin to 2x2 items view in grid view?

Tags: android, staggered-gridview

Want to add margin to gridview in the following manner.
Left margin for 2,4, 2,9, 12,14,..
Right margin for 3,5, 8,10, 13,15,..

Here is my code snippet which I tried to set margin to 2x2 items in grid view...

i.e positions - ..,2,3,4,5,..,7,8,9,10,..,12,13,14,15,..,17,18,19,20,.. like wise.

for 2,3,4,5 & 12,13,14,15,.. Getting the expected output. but my case failed for 7,8,9,10 & 17,18,19,20 series.

Help me to solve this. Confused to solve this mathematical puzzle.
Thanks in advance.

```
public class BoxFeedAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
private List<BoxFeedResult> boxFeedResults;
private Context mContext;
private RecyclerViewItemClickListener viewItemClickListener;

private final int LARGE_TYPE = 0;
private final int SMALL_TYPE = 1;
private final int PROGRESS_TYPE = 2;

private int GRID_VIEW_MARGIN_LEFT = 0;
private int GRID_VIEW_MARGIN_RIGHT = 0;
private int GRID_VIEW_MARGIN_TOP = 0;
private int GRID_VIEW_MARGIN_BOTTOM = 0;
private int GRID_VIEW_ROW_MARGIN = 0;

public BoxFeedAdapter(Context context, RecyclerViewItemClickListener viewItemClickListener) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.viewItemClickListener = viewItemClickListener;
    boxFeedResults = new ArrayList<>();
    GRID_VIEW_MARGIN_LEFT = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.empty_dimen);
    GRID_VIEW_MARGIN_RIGHT = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.empty_dimen);
    GRID_VIEW_MARGIN_TOP = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.channel_row_padding);
    GRID_VIEW_MARGIN_BOTTOM = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.empty_dimen);
    GRID_VIEW_ROW_MARGIN = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.channel_row_padding_left);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    if (viewType == SMALL_TYPE) {
        View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_box_feed_series_banner, null);
        return new BoxFeedSeriesListViewHolder(layoutView);
    } else if (viewType == LARGE_TYPE) {
        View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_box_feed_episode_banner, null);
        return new BoxFeedEpisodeViewHolder(layoutView);
    } else {
        View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.progress_item, null);
        return new ProgressViewHolder(layoutView);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    if (holder instanceof BoxFeedSeriesListViewHolder) {
        StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParams.setFullSpan(false);
    if ((position - 1) % 2 == 0) {
        layoutParams.setMargins(GRID_VIEW_ROW_MARGIN, GRID_VIEW_MARGIN_TOP, GRID_VIEW_MARGIN_RIGHT, GRID_VIEW_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
    } else {
        layoutParams.setMargins(GRID_VIEW_MARGIN_LEFT, GRID_VIEW_MARGIN_TOP, GRID_VIEW_ROW_MARGIN, GRID_VIEW_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
    }
    holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    final BoxFeedResult singleFeed = boxFeedResults.get(position);
    final BoxFeedSeriesListViewHolder viewHolder = (BoxFeedSeriesListViewHolder) holder;

    Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(singleFeed.getA4MediumUrl())
            .placeholder(R.drawable.bg_black)
            .into(viewHolder.seriesImage);

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, singleFeed.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            viewItemClickListener.onItemClickListioner(singleFeed, viewHolder.seriesImage, position);
        }
    });
} else if (holder instanceof BoxFeedEpisodeViewHolder) {

    StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.setFullSpan(true);
    holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    final BoxFeedResult singleFeed = boxFeedResults.get(position);
    final BoxFeedEpisodeViewHolder viewHolder = (BoxFeedEpisodeViewHolder) holder;
    Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(singleFeed.getAspectMediumUrl())
            .placeholder(R.drawable.bg_black)
            .into(viewHolder.episodeImage);

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, singleFeed.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
} else {
    StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.setFullSpan(true);
    holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
}
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return boxFeedResults.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    switch (boxFeedResults.get(position).getTileType()) {
        case “large":
            return LARGE_TYPE;
        case “small":
            return SMALL_TYPE;
        default:
            return PROGRESS_TYPE;
    }
}

public void addList(List<BoxFeedResult> feedResults) {
    this.boxFeedResults = feedResults;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

Expected output is[image]

Comment: Those boxes are same height ? 0,1,6 are same and remaining others also same ?

Comment: No 0 has different height, 1,6,... are same in height and width...